# Replacing Furniture Cam Dowel & Lock Pin

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

I have a wooden dresser in perfect condition, which started to come apart. When I looked closely it seems the cam locks started to crack causing the drawers to fall apart. I have searched all major hardware retailers and could not identify a the correct name to find a replacement part.

Would appreciate any help on identifying the replacement part name or suggestions on repairing this problem.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: When you say the cam locks are breaking are you referring to the cams themselves are cracking and thus are no longer able to hold firmly to the head of the pin?

Comment: Replacement cam lock fittings can be found on Amazon as shown here. https://www.amazon.com/Silver-Tone-Furniture-Connecter-Fittings/dp/B00HG7G0MM Use care selecting parts are there are multiple sizes although the ones linked look to be similar size to yours.

Comment: VTC - This is basically a shopping question which is off topic here.

Comment: As depicted in one of the photos, pieces of the cams themselves started chipping. Also, the heads of the dowel/pin started to snap off. I have searched high and low for replacements or work arounds to get the drawers fixed and hit a head end. One of the challenges is the fact that there are so many different sizes and types.

Comment: In the USA, your local Home Depot sells both dowel pins and cam locks in separate packages.

Answer (score 1):

Many places call them Cam Connectors ( see: http://www.homedepot.com/s/cam%2520Connecter?NCNI-5 ) and Cam Screws ( see: http://www.homedepot.com/s/cam%2520screw?NCNI-5 ) or take Michael Karas' lead and check out the "Customers who bought this item also bought" section for other offers.

Answer (score 0):

> **... causing the *drawers* to fall apart ... suggestions on repairing this problem.**

Those cam-locks are available at national retailers for £3 for 50.

For wooden drawers, I'd use wooden dowels and wood-glue in the existing hole.

If necessary, cut a plug for the cam recess then re-drill the hole for the dowel.

I'd maybe put a couple of extra dowels in for added strength. Or apply glue to any existing unglued dowels.

Comment: The drawers use six locking cam/dowels and the rest are the wooden dowels. Thank you for your suggestion in using the glue for the wooden dowels. The major problem I'm having is finding the replacement and/or work around for the locking cam/dowel.

Comment: @iakoubtchik: I'm suggesting replacing the broken metal cam-lock and the cam-dowel with a simple wooden dowel glued into the same place using the same holes (enlarged a little i necessary.